# What to do? Recruiter pushy with current salary, revealed on phone

Tags: hiring-process, recruitment

First of all, I'm aware this topic has been discussed previously but didn't find a similar situation.

I'm taking part in a hiring process and at the very beginning the recruiter asked me for my current salary which I mistakenly revealed over the phone (I know, I shouldn't have done that) but it seemed to be within their range for this role.

As the process has moved forward I'm now asked to provide further and comprehensive details about my current salary and benefits in a written form yet I don't have a firm offer and some aspects of the position still need to be defined by the company.

I sent the form back without disclosing the current salary and expectations, noting down the expected salary would be in line with the market conditions, benefits and location.

The recruiter, who is part of the HR team, wrote back insisting to have my current salary in the form.

What should I do now?

- Back off and write those details as revealed on the phone.
- Retaliate claiming those demands are somewhat intrusive and unneeded at this point.
- Suggestions?

I'm terrible at negotiation and the question at the beginning of the process caught me off-guard but I'm really interested in the role and seeking to have a win-win outcome.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: If I want to know my salary, I'd have to ask my wife... (she's my accountant).  She wouldn't let me pass that information out anyway..

Comment: This is one of the hallmarks of "Sleazeball recruiters."  Proceed at your own risk, but this is where I'd break it off with them, were I you.

Comment: The standard response to "I have to put something" is "just put a dollar if it makes the computer happy." I mean, the computer system is kind of their problem but you're just trying to make everything go smoothly for the both of you so may as well help.

Comment: The negotiation part does not oblige you to disclose the current salary...Write off this opportunity and do not repeat the mistake in the future.

Comment: From personal experience, the only reason they want to know what your salary is now is so they can lowball you.  I agree with @WesleyLong here - I'd break off with them ASAP.

Answer (score 8):

I would refuse to give the details, that's between you and your current employer. Otherwise you weaken your negotiating position, and there is no clear job offer anyway, so you might just be doing some free market research for them.

Employers are aware that they shouldn't be asking for these details, so they're just trying it on. If they seriously want you as an employee, they'll do without.

Answer (score 4):

> noting down the expected salary would be in line with the market
>   conditions, benefits and location

Perfect response.

Just ignore the question for the time being. If they want you, they'll find a way around their own 'procedures'. In the meantime, read some books on negotiating; it isn't too hard, especially if you're prepared to walk away.

Comment: That was my response regarding the salary expectations, which the recruiter accepted, but she insisted on my current salary (with 'current salary' in bold and underlined). 

I've read a lot about negotiation but when it comes to doing it, I suck! Need much more practice though, but not sure if this is the right time. I should not walk away of this opportunity.... Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Why do you suck? You already have got a job, just do not back down when making demands, and most importantly, keep yourself informed in the going rates, and the cost of living when relocating.

Comment: @Rodolfo: If you can't walk away from an opportunity, you're negotiating from a position of weakness. They want you, you want a decent salary; but by giving them your current salary, you've told them the minimum salary that you'd accept to work for them.